# Switch change from two to one

Tags: switch

I have two switches in my kitchen one operates the cabinet lights and the other operates the ceiling light. I want to make the cabinet light direct so thatt i only have the switch to operate the ceiling light. What or which wires i have to join for direct and which ones goes in the switch.
Regards
Subhajit [image]

Comment: Yikes! Whatever you do, ensure that there is no bare copper showing like you've got on the red wire in the blue circle or the little strand of copper sticking out of the grey sheath in the red circle (or is that a red string?)! In the US, at least, the _only_ wire allowed to be bare within a box is the ground, and no matter _where_ in the world you are, bare wires could touch, causing a short at best and a fire at worst.

Comment: First you have to verify that the 2 lights are on the same branch circuit. If both lights are on the same circuit moving the conductor feeding the lights over to the other switch is all that is needed. 

I would push in on the red wire it appears the back stab has slipped, I do not like back stabs in general but they probably paid for my son’s college.

Comment: Hi,  can you tell us what you mean by "direct" ?   Do you want, for example, the cabinet lights to always be on, i.e. connected directly to the hot feed?

Comment: Yes.. as i have it attached to a remote so i can control the cabinet light from there

Answer (score 0):

Connect the two wires going to the switch with a wire nut.I wouldn't, I would want to be able to switch it off.